# Reading formatted lines from stringstream performantly

Tags: c++

For loading large amounts of vertices from a text file, I'm loading the whole file into memory and then I'd like to scan each line for the three floats.
The following works, but I'd like to know whether it's good or wasteful.

```
std::stringstream sstr;
sstr << file.rdbuf();    // file is an ifstream

for (uint i=0; i<num_verts; ++i)
{
    sstr.getline(line, bufsz);
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    iss >> verts[i].x >> verts[i].y >> verts[i].z;
}
```

On the reference site cplusplus.com I found the following for `istringstream`:

> (2) initialization constructor: Constructs an istringstream object with a copy of str as content.

So if `istringstream` is really copying each string upon construction, then that's very wasteful, especially since I already have a stringstream in the first place.

Compared with `sscanf`, the above is indeed quite slow: 1.94 seconds vs. 0.56s for `sscanf`.

Is the string being copied upon initialization of `iss`?

How would one read formatted values while simultaneously advancing in the string line-wise with just the stringstream?

Or less specific: What's the C++ method for the above case that's equally well performing as `sscanf`?

Comment: iostreams are _amazingly_ powerful and flexible, but unfortunately, we don't need that power 99% of the time and pay the penalty anyway.  The normal thing(s) to do are (A) ignore it, (B) use `sscanf`, (C) write your own parser, or (D) `boost::spirit`

Comment: Hmmm why not read directly from `file`? [`ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) provides everything that [`basic_istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) does. Including formatted input, and you are doing two copies. One for `line`, then one for `iss`, instead of just extracting data. Well actually 3 if you count `sstr << file.rdbuf();`.

Comment: @luk32 I concur about the first one, but the second provides per-line validation. Wanting `int` values in trios per line reading straight off the file stream isn't the same. `if (file >> val1 >> val2 >> val3) { we have a trio}` looks well and good, but will also succeed for content like `1 2\n3 4\n5 6` (read as two trios), or `1 2 3 4\n5 6` (read as two trios), when in both cases, the input is *ill-formed*. I concur with the first extraneous copy removal, but the second has merit. I would also use `std::getline` rather than the stream's.

Answer (score 2):

OK, following my comment. I made some a tests for you.

**Codes:**

bloated_read.cpp:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct Vert {
 double x,y,z;
};

int main(){
const int num_verts = 1000000;
const int buff_size = 1024;
std::vector<Vert> verts(num_verts);
std::ifstream file("numbers");
std::stringstream sstr;
sstr << file.rdbuf();    // file is an ifstream
char *line = new char [buff_size];

for (int i=0; i<num_verts; ++i)
{
    sstr.getline(line, buff_size);
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    iss >> verts[i].x >> verts[i].y >> verts[i].z;
}

return 0;
}
```

*Please note i skipped the common includes and `Vert` definition for the following codes.*

slimmed_read.cpp:

```
int main(){
const int num_verts = 1000000;
std::vector<Vert> verts(num_verts);
std::ifstream file("numbers");

for (int i=0; i<num_verts; ++i)
{
    file >> verts[i].x >> verts[i].y >> verts[i].z;
}

return 0;
}
```

sscanf_read.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio> //sscanf
int main(){
const int num_verts = 1000000;
const int buff_size = 1024;
std::vector<Vert> verts(num_verts);
std::ifstream file("numbers");
char *line = new char [buff_size];

for (int i=0; i<num_verts; ++i)
{
    file.getline(line, buff_size);
    sscanf(line, "%f %f %f", &verts[i].x, &verts[i].y, &verts[i].z );
}

return 0;
}
```

**Results:**

I did two tests for num_verts 10^5 and 10^6, so I changed input file contents and appropriate line in code. Total wall-clock running time:

```
size | bloated | slim   | sscanf
10^5 |  0.401s | 0.242s | 0.190s
10^6 |  4.041s | 2.392s | 1.896s
```

Seems consistent. You can brush off 40% by using `ifstream` directly and get 25% more if you use `sscanf` to parse the `line`. The file for `10^6` had `56 444KB`, so the *total* parsing efficiency was `29,07MB/s`. I would say that there still is some room for improvement, however on my system I think this is on borderline of being HDD bound.

**Conclusions:**

I would go for `sscanf` version if further speed ups are not needed. It is still fairly simple to implement and understand.  Also check the speed of your HDDs to make sure it is worth a shot.

One should also not that there is no mixing between c and c++ style of accessing data. Data is extracted into a buffer using c++ facilities, and c functions are used to read the buffer. I guess it's ok.

Comment: While interesting, the two are not equivalent. pulling three values straight off the file stream does not detect ill formed *lines*, which is honestly the point of real merit using getline/istringstream in the first place. If that isn't a requirement, I concur; use the file stream directly and eliminate the middle-man.

Comment: @WhozCraig I was merely comparing speed. You can easily extend the codes for input validation, and I believe it is not a problem in any presented cases. And I believe there are better ways than introducing and intermediate copy. Regarding your comment under the question: Even if you say, one copy in the original code had it purpose, I strongly disagree. It allows to perform a check, yes. However, I didn't see any check for input validation, therefore I didn't feel compelled at all to include it in my examples, nor comment on it. However I do appreciate comment and think it's worth noting.