# How to read 64bit int file with markers the fastest?

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream

I'm trying to read some data from a file to fill the following data structures:

> ```c++
> typedef uint64_t t_feat; 
>
> typedef pair<vector<t_feat>, int> t_featfam;
> ```

Each log file contains several such families, so I want to save them all in a vector.
The logfiles that have a very simple formatting:

> ```c++
> line = "-": start a new family
>
> line = "#": family ends here
>
> line = 64bit unsigned integer (as string): add this value to the family
>
> line = "!": mark the following integer as important (exactly one is marked like this in each family), the marking is done by setting the the second value of the family to the index of the important element
> ```

There are no mistakes in the files, so every `!` is followed by an integer, all families start and end properly and there are no additional spaces or anything (only exception is a possible empty line at the file end).

Right now I'm using the following code:

```c++
void read_data_from_file(const string &fname, vector<t_featfam> &data)
{
    ifstream f;
    f.open(fname, ios::in);
    while (!f.eof())
    {
        string currentline;
        getline(f, currentline);
        if (currentline == "" || currentline == "#")
            continue;
        else if (currentline == "-")
            data.push_back(t_featfam());
        else if (currentline == "!")
            data.back().second = data.back().first.size();
        else
        {
            istringstream iss(currentline);
            t_feat value;
            iss >> value;
            data.back().first.push_back(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but feels horribly inefficient and probably is...
If it would be just numbers, I would certainly use only fstreams, but as it is, I'm not sure how to do that properly. Can anyone hint me the right direction? This should be possible somehow. I'm using Visual Studio, and don't mind VS-specific solutions, but don't wanna include boost.

edit2:
now a really working version, using steves codes, and improved by the ideas from luk32...
4 times faster then aboves code...

```c++
void read_data_from_file(const string &fname, vector<t_featfam> &data)
{
    ifstream f;
    f.open(fname, ios::in);
    char* currentline = new char [30];
    while (!f.eof())
    {
        f.getline(currentline, 30);
        switch (currentline[0])
        {
        case '\0':
        case '#':
            break;
        case '-':
            data.push_back(t_featfam());
            break;
        case '!':
            data.back().second = data.back().first.size();
            break;
        default:
            data.back().first.push_back(stoull(currentline));
            break;
        }
    }
    delete currentline;
}
```

Comment: `int` as a type for indexing into a vector is a bad choice. You should prefer `std::vector::size_type` (usually `size_t`).

Comment: @pmr: very few people care about that at all.

Comment: `if(currentline == "" && currentline == "#")` ?? O_ó What it is  supposed to mean? @MooingDuck Well if you gonna have `2^32` lines you should. =) It is probably about good habit of keeping types consistent.

Comment: Checking for `eof` is also not a good way to read from a stream because `eof` is only going to be set after you tried to read it and that read will fail.

Comment: @luk oups... that should be a || instead of a &&... changed, thanks

Comment: Also if you have a formatted input, using a `sscanf` on `currentline` is probably faster than making `iss` because that copies the buffer. I did a test for other person. The codes look very similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437789. Your seems like the "bloated" version. Well you do one stupid copy less at start. On top of that, I think I need to revise it. I am not sure which optimization flag I used there. If it was under `O2` the `c++`  solutions were inherently impaired. Still my bet for best case goes for `getline` + `sscanf`.

Comment: I just noticed that you use global function `getline` not the [`istream` member method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline). I still it might be beneficial to change to a `char*` buffer and avoid the copy.

Comment: @luk32 i now tried your suggestions... awesome, thanks a lot :) That was a huge improvement, i edited my new code in the start post.

Comment: oups... and i butchered the conversion to int :( meh

Comment: but now finally... this version works... and is fast :) thanks everyone

Comment: @Mahrgell you really don't need to be doing `char* currentline = new char [30]`, just use a `std::string`. It's more or less the same thing, but safer

Comment: @Mahrgell don't edit your question to reflect the changes you've made - since this is a Q&A site, upvote relevant answers, and possibly accept one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do something along the lines of the following:

- move `currentline` outside the loop - prevents reallocs every time around the loop
- use a switch statement on the first `char` of `currentline` so we jump instead of multiple `if/else` statements
- use `std::stoull` instead of a `stringstream` to convert `currentline` to `uint64_t`

Here's the function (not tested to see if it compiles, just wrote it up)

```
void read_data_from_file(const string &fname, vector<t_featfam> &data)
{
    ifstream f;
    f.open(fname, ios::in);
    string currentline;
    while (!f.eof())
    {
        getline(f, currentline);
        switch (currentline.c_str()[0])
        {
            case '\0':
            case '#':
                break;
            case '-':
                data.push_back(t_featfam());
                break;
            case '!':
                data.back().second = data.back().first.size();
                break;
            default:
                data.back().first.push_back(std::stoull(currentline));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i improved this a bit further by using a char* instead of a string... This is much better then what i originally had :)

Comment: @Mahrgell I don't necessarily agree that `char*` is better than `string`. If you insist on using a `char*`, then just create a char array on the stack. You don't pay for a heap allocation, and it will have automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time is lost in the memory allocations. You have one allocation when you call `getline()` and another one when you construct the `istringstream`. Each allocation costs roughly 250 cycles on my system. So, you can save roughly 500 cycles per line that you read.

You can eliminate the allocations altogether if you use `mmap()` to map the entire file into your address space. Once you have everything in a single large array of `char`, you can relatively easily parse it without any need to copy lines out of that large array.

Answer (score 0):

How long is it taking to process the entire file? If speed is really an issue here, and since you should have plenty of memory if you're running this program on a PC, you could use the equivalent of seek to end, tell, seek to beginning to get the size of the entire log file, allocate that much memory, then read in the entire file into a a large buffer. Then use memchr () to scan for every occurrence of "-", to determine the number of pairs, optionally create an array of pointers (pre-allocated based on maximum number of pairs for a given file size) then do a one time resize of the vector of pairs (or a one time new if using a pointer to vector to pairs). Then parse the buffer again to fill in the pairs via index or iterator instead of push_back(). Although this method scans the file buffer twice, it may compensate by avoiding internal dynamic resizes that would occurs with a bunch of push_backs().

Another option would be to put the pair count at the start or end of the log file, which would eliminate the first scan used to get number of pairs. If you have an idea of the maximum file size, you could just allocate sufficient memory to handle the largest expected log file, which would eliminate having to determine the file size before allocation.