# Using a loop to read in data from a text file with multiple lines

Tags: c++

I am new to the C++ language and have been doing circles on how to get my program to behave properly. I do not by any means expect anybody to just do it for me, but would like some help figuring this out.

I have been given this data set:

```
AGUA CANYON 8900 2.4 3.1 2.7 1.9 1.5 0.9 1.9 2.7 2.3 2.1 2.2 2.4
BEAVER DAMS 8000 2.9 2.8 3.4 3.4 2.2 0.9 1.1 1.7 1.9 2.4 2.7 2.7
BEAVER DIVIDE   8280 3.3 3.1 3.3 3.3 2.6 1.5 1.4 1.8 1.8 2.2 2.9 3.3
```

With 75 other pieces of information.  And my code so far is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void)

{
ifstream inFile;
ofstream outputFile;
string Station;
int Elevation;
double Precipitation;
int count = 0;

inFile.open("monthlyPrecipitation.txt");

outputFile.open("AnnualPrecipitaion.txt");

outputFile << "Annual Preciptitaion Report" << endl << endl;
outputFile << "Weather Station\t\tElevation\tPrecipitation" << endl;


    inFile >> Station;
    for (string Station; getline(inFile, Station);)
    {
        outputFile << Station << endl;
    }



return 0;
```

}

I am having trouble having the program make it look like this

```
Annual Precipitation Report

Weather Station       Elevation  Precipitatio
AGUA CANYON             8900        26.1
BEAVER DAMS             8000        28.1
BEAVER DIVIDE            8280        30.5
```

Comment: There is my problem, I am in a basic c++ class at Utah State University and our professor has failed to go over most of the information leading up to this.  I have spent over 6 hours today researching this topic, and finally just decided to ask here.  I am limited to my coding on this assignment, so that what you have mentioned doesn't really apply to what i have been shown so far.  Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: There are too many questions like this on StackOverflow.  Try searching the internet for "StackOverflow c++ read file structure" or even "StackOverflow c++ read file tab separated"

Answer (score 1):

Try to make use of class [std::stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)

You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23438539/2648826) answer for more details.

Ex:

```
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    iss >> var1 >> var2 >> var3;
```